# Firefox getBoundingClientRect() does not account for transforms

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, css-transforms

I'm adding some SVG Paths to my web page, but am having difficulty with Firefox 43.0. It appears that when I apply `transform: scale(0.1)` to my path, Firefox does not update the bounding client rectangle (via `getBoundingClientRect()`)

Here's a screenshot of my Path before the transform, and the correct bounding rectangle:

[image: Path without transform]

And here it is with the transform applied, with the visual clearly outside the bounding box:

[image: Path with transform]

By contrast, here is Chrome updating its bounding box as expected. (Note the constrained proportions.)

[image: Path with transform in Chrome]

This problem isn't present on either Chrome or Edge. I did find [this old bug from 2012](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=591718) which says the problem was fixed in version 12.0, and the documentation states:

> Starting from Gecko 12.0 (Firefox 12.0 / Thunderbird 12.0 / SeaMonkey 2.9), the effect of CSS transforms is considered when computing the element's bounding rectangle.

...which doesn't seem to be true. For the other browsers, I was scaling down my circle to 10% of its original size, then computing the coordinate offset from the client rectangle to center it on its original 100% scale position. However, since the client rectangle isn't updated after the transform in Firefox, it's messing up the calculations.

How do I work around this for Firefox?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by transform attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transforms can be set via attributes e.g.

```
<path transform="scale(0.1)" d="..."/>
```

or CSS as you're doing. Using CSS is the newer way to do it; the SVG 1.1 specification only specifies attribute transforms.

[getBoundingClientRect doesn't take CSS transforms into account](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1066435) currently on Firefox but it does take transform attributes into account.

Comment: Adding this attribute definitely fixes the bounding box issue I was seeing in the above screenshots. I was afraid this adding attribute could be problematic since I was attempting to animate the `transform` property with CSS, but I was able to make the animation to work anyways.

Comment: Is there anything I can use to get the position of an element in Firefox with CSS transforms? Unfortunately, I don't have the option for attributes.

Comment: @Norbert Download the source code to Firefox, fix the issue and upload a patch to [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1066435) That's how I got started when I saw my first Firefox bug.